# How to map two different classes into one ViewModel with Automapper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, automapper

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC3 application in C# and Razor. The architecture of the application is divided in Data Access Layer (EF classes + Repository), Service Layer, Controller, ViewModels and View.

In the controller I obtain from my Service Layer:

1. From the method `Product GetProduct(id)`, a `Product` object which contains all the information about a product to be displayed in the View
2. From the method `Filter GetFilter()` a `Filter` object that contains all the info that are used for the search filter such list of products to be chosen from a dropdownlist, etc...

Now if I use AutoMapper how can I map these information in a `SelectProductViewModel` class?

```
public class SelectProductViewModel
{
    public Product ProductToDisplay { get; set; }
    public Filter SearchFilter { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoMapper is used to map between a single source type to a single destination type. You cannot use it in this context. So it could be as simple as:

```
var model = new SelectProductViewModel
{
    ProductToDisplay = service.GetProduct(id),
    SearchFilter = service.GetFilter()
};
```

Comment: thanks! Since it does not work in this case, I still do not understand which added value might give automapper to an application

Comment: Automapper has value when you need to copy properties from an object to a POCO or DTO, cutting down the grunt work. This is its purpose and it should be used only for that.

Comment: @MikeSw , when you said object did you mean `ViewModel's` object ? because `POCO` is domain model or the real model right ?

Comment: @stom POCO is any object which doesn't have db traits associated with